# Repeat song on YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I was just wondering if we have a repeat song option on YouTube? I know we have the option of creating a playlist but didn't manage to find any repeat option. So is there any way we can repeat the same video without manually doing it every time?

Answer (score 1):

You just right click and click **Loop** or you use other site like this one http://youtuberepeater.com/!

Comment: Little more details would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the YouTube player has that functionality built into it.

However, if you are using Chrome (I am sure other browsers would have a similar extension) you can add the [Auto Refresh Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh/ifooldnmmcmlbdennkpdnlnbgbmfalko/related?hl=en).

After it is installed, set the refresh time to the same time as the YouTube video and away you go.